# stack level too deep (SystemStackError) DFS

Tags: ruby, graph

I am having a problem with `stack level too deep` while performing **DFS algorithm** to find the largest component. The thing is that I am transforming map(.osm) file to a graph. And I want to find the largest component. However, working with small map (zoom is bigger) it works but taking a larger graph it gives me above state error, can you help me?
Here is my DFS code which causes the problem:

```
def dfsFunction (vertex)
    @dfs[vertex] = true
    @component[@componentIndex] << vertex
    adjectenVertices = []
    @edges.each do |edge|
        if edge.v1.id == vertex.id
            adjectenVertices << edge.v2
        elsif edge.v2.id == vertex.id
            adjectenVertices << edge.v1
        end
    end
    adjectenVertices.each_with_index do |vertex|
        if @dfs[vertex] == false
            dfsFunction(vertex)
        end
    end
end




@dfs = {}
    @vertices.each do |id,vertex|
        @dfs[vertex] = false
    end
    @component = {}
    @componentIndex = -1
    @dfs.each do |vertex, boolean|
        if @dfs[vertex] == false
            @componentIndex = @componentIndex +1
            @component[@componentIndex] = []
            dfsFunction(vertex)
        end
    end
```

Comment: What line is the error pointing to?

Comment: Also can you include the sample data you're using?

Comment: A simple example of the values of `@vertices` and `@edges` would be helpful. I see no justification, incidentally, for the Rails tag. The "graph" tag is OK but I don't think it serves a purpose. You don't need "Ruby" in the title because it is a tag.

Comment: The error is not pointing to any line... but the graph is around 22k lines of XML code

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that you use recursion and it is getting deep for complex graphs. For each recursion the stack must be increased to hold the result value.
To solve this issue you can do two things: change to a loop or rewrite your recursion that is tail call optimized and enable the tail call optimization for ruby (for some explanation have a look here: http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-tco/).

I have made a small version of it, which is using a while loop. I hope it helps...

```
class Edge
  attr_reader :left, :right

  def initialize(left, right)
    @left, @right = left, right
  end

  def vertexes
    [left, right]
  end
end

class Graph
  attr_reader :vertexes, :edges

  def initialize(vertexes, edges)
    @vertexes, @edges = vertexes, edges
  end

  def add_edges(new_edges)
    new_edges.each { |edge| add_edge(edge) }
  end

  def add_edge(edge)
    add_vertex(edge.left)
    add_vertex(edge.right)
    @edges << edge
    @edges.uniq!
    edge
  end

  def add_vertex(vertex)
    @vertexes << vertex
    @vertexes.uniq!
    vertex
  end

  def edges_for(vertex) 
    edges.select { |edge| edge.left == vertex || edge.right == vertex }
  end
end

module DFS
  def self.components(graph)
    vertexes = graph.vertexes.clone
    graph.vertexes.map do |vertex|
      next unless vertexes.delete(vertex)
      component = Graph.new([vertex], [])
      edges = graph.edges_for(vertex)
      while (new_vertexes = edges.map(&:vertexes).flatten & vertexes).any? do
        component.add_edges(edges)
        edges = new_vertexes.map { |new_vertex| graph.edges_for(new_vertex) }.flatten
        vertexes -= new_vertexes
      end
      component.add_edges(edges)
      component
    end.compact
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

MRI has tail recursion optimization switched off by default. But one might turn it on:

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_option = {
 tailcall_optimization: true,
 trace_instruction: false
}
```

also, the code itself must use tail recursion like:

```
  def test(v)
    return unless v > 0
    p v
    test(v-1) 
  end
```

Instead of:

```
def test(v)
  test(v-1) if v > 0
  p v
end
```